# ¿En Docker, Como integrar WebSocket en Servicio LAMP con un proxy reverso intermediario?

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, websocket, lamp

Buen día amigos, tengo el siguiente archivo `docker-compose.yml` con el cual instalo un proxy reverso y un stack LAMP con el servicio phpmyadmin,

***Nota:*** prácticamente lo he creado desde 0 y le he agregado nuevas funcionalidades a lo mejor no sea perfecto.

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  reverse-proxy:
    env_file:
      - .env
    container_name: Proxy-Server
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy:alpine
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
      - /etc/nginx/certs
    ports:
      - "${LH_HOST_MACHINE_UNSECURE_HOST_PORT:-80}:80"
      - "${LH_HOST_MACHINE_SECURE_HOST_PORT:-443}:443"
    depends_on:
      - webserver
      - phpmyadmin
    networks:
      - lamp-network
    extra_hosts:
      - "${LH_WEB_SERVER_DOMAIN}:127.0.0.1"
      - "${LH_PHPMYADMIN_DOMAIN}:127.0.0.1"
    environment:
      - TRUST_DOWNSTREAM_PROXY=true
      - ENABLE_WEBSOCKETS=true
    labels:
      - "lh2.setup.description=Proxy Server"
      - "lh2.setup.role=reverse-proxy"
  webserver:
    env_file:
      - .env
    container_name: ${LH_SYSTEM_NAME}-Web-Server
    build:
      context: ./bin/${LH_PHP_ENVIRONMENT}
    restart: always
    expose:
      - 80
      - 443
    networks:
      - lamp-network
    depends_on:
      - database
    volumes:
      - ${LH_PROJECT_ROOT}:/var/www/html:rw
      - ${LH_PROJECT_ROOT}${LH_DOCUMENT_ROOT}:/var/www/html/public:rw
      - ${LH_VHOSTS_DIR}:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled
      - ${LH_PHP_INI}:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
      - ${LH_LOG_DIR}:/var/log/apache2
      - ${LH_LOG_CRON}:/var/log/cron
    environment:
      LH_WEB_MASTER: ${LH_WEB_MASTER}
      VIRTUAL_HOST: ${LH_WEB_SERVER_DOMAIN}
      LH_APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT: ${LH_APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT}
      LH_DOCUMENT_ROOT: ${LH_DOCUMENT_ROOT}
      HOST_MACHINE_MYSQL_PORT: ${LH_HOST_MACHINE_MYSQL_PORT}
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${LH_MYSQL_DATABASE}
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${LH_MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_USER: ${LH_MYSQL_USER}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${LH_MYSQL_PASSWORD}
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
    labels:
      - "lh2.setup.description=Web Server"
      - "lh2.setup.role=webserver"
  database:
    env_file:
      - .env
    build:
      context: ./bin/${LH_DATABASE}
    container_name: ${LH_SYSTEM_NAME}-${LH_DATABASE}
    restart: always
    networks:
      - lamp-network
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:${LH_HOST_MACHINE_MYSQL_PORT}:${LH_HOST_MACHINE_MYSQL_PORT}"
    volumes:
      - ${LH_MYSQL_INITDB_DIR}:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
      - ${LH_MYSQL_DATA_DIR}:/var/lib/mysql
      - ${LH_MYSQL_LOG_DIR}:/var/log/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${LH_MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${LH_MYSQL_DATABASE}
      MYSQL_USER: ${LH_MYSQL_USER}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${LH_MYSQL_PASSWORD}
    labels:
      - "lh2.setup.description=Database Server"
      - "lh2.setup.role=database"
  phpmyadmin:
    env_file:
      - .env
    container_name: ${LH_SYSTEM_NAME}-phpmyadmin
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - database
    environment:
      VIRTUAL_HOST: ${LH_PHPMYADMIN_DOMAIN}
      PMA_HOST: database
      PMA_PORT: 3306
      PMA_USER: root
      PMA_PASSWORD: ${LH_MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${LH_MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_USER: ${LH_MYSQL_USER}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${LH_MYSQL_PASSWORD}
      UPLOAD_LIMIT: ${LH_UPLOAD_LIMIT}
      MEMORY_LIMIT: ${LH_MEMORY_LIMIT}
    volumes:
      - /sessions
      - ${LH_PHP_INI}:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/php-phpmyadmin.ini
    networks:
      - lamp-network
    labels:
      - "lh2.setup.description=phpMyAdmin"
      - "lh2.setup.role=phpmyadmin"
networks:
  lamp-network:
    driver: bridge
```

Todo esto funciona perfectamente en mi equipo local Windows 11, pero ahora quisiera integrarle funcionalidad de websocket, comprendo que para eso, debo utilizar certificado SSL por eso estoy habilitando el puerto 443, pero no encuentro/un ejemplo o en la documentación que cosas me hacen falta o que debo agregar para:

1. que cambios debo hacer en mí archivo hosts, actualmente fue necesario agregar esta línea para redirigir los request http:

```
# Developer Area Docker
127.0.0.1 lh-2.dock lh-2.pma.dock lh-2.cron.dock lh-2.inc.dock
# End of section
```

2. como generar el certificado SSL utilizando el archivo yml, imagino que debe haber alguna imagen servicio que lo haga y no requerir alterar la imagen de mi proxy, más que incorporar o compartir volumenes entre contenedores.

aquí si estoy perdido por que no se ni por donde empezar.

3. que debo modificar en mi archivo yml, servicio reverse_proxy para redirigir las peticiones wss:// al contendor del servicio webserver.

Aquí sí estoy aún más perdido por que no se ni por donde empezar.

4. que debo modificar en mi servicio webserver / LAMP para capturar lo que el reverse proxy le envié.

Aquí sí estoy aún más más perdido por que no se ni por dónde empezar.

Si se requiere más información me lo hacen saber para agregarla.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno me respondo a mi mismo con las respuesta que encontre a cada pregunta y se las dejo por si a alguien le llegan a servir de utilidad.

> 1. que cambios debo hacer en mí archivo hosts, actualmente fue necesario
>    agregar esta línea para redirigir los request http:

***Respuesta:*** no hay que hacer cambios en esta seccion.

> 2. como generar el certificado SSL utilizando el archivo yml, imagino que
>    debe haber alguna imagen servicio que lo haga y no requerir alterar la
>    imagen de mi proxy, más que incorporar o compartir volumenes entre
>    contenedores.

***Respuesta:*** Existe dos formas de hacerlo:

a. Utilizar el **companion** de un nginx-proxy por ejemplo [este](https://github.com/nginx-proxy/acme-companion).

b. Utilizar [`mkcert`](https://github.com/FiloSottile/mkcert) para generar los certificados SSL.

> 3. que debo modificar en mi archivo yml, servicio reverse_proxy para
>    redirigir las peticiones wss:// al contendor del servicio webserver.

***Respuesta:*** para especificamente poder implementar `wss://` se requiere de estar corriendo certificados ssl y en funcion al puerto `443` websocket se aprobecha de la capa TCP del protocolo para mover los datos de forma segura, obviamente que no es suficiente y en el caso de api requerirar evaluar otras necesidades entorno a la seguridad, [lectura recomendada](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_servers).

> 4. que debo modificar en mi servicio webserver / LAMP para capturar lo
>    que el reverse proxy le envié.

***Respuesta:*** no hay nada que modificar, el trabajo al final lo hace el proxy-nginx resposable de ser el puente entre `cliente`-`proxy`-`backend`

El cliente se comunica por https con el proxy en ambos sentidos y el proxy en la red interna usa el puerto 80 para comunicarce con el backend.

***Lo que sigue:***
Estare actualizando esta respuesta para incluir un proyecto con el que he solucionado todas estas dudas y lo he implementado.